# I see the Biosphere has frozen

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

So, apparently The Biosphere (our BIO.SE chat room) [has been frozen due to inactivity](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1997/2019/1/28).

Obviously not a big deal (since apparently nobody used it frequently enough to [avoid being frozen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention)):

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.

But...it wasn't completely ignored or altogether not useful at times sooo..

**How do we get it unfrozen??**

[image]

Comment: Seems like a moderator can do it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70198/how-do-i-unfreeze-a-frozen-chat-room/70201#70201

Comment: Thanks, @Bryan. I was apparently too lazy to MetaMeta my question, but apparently not lazy enough to throw together a gif of a hampster getting microwaved :p.

Comment: Excitement can overcome laziness :)

Comment: I just... don't understand why you have to make this post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mods can unfreeze a chatroom.

The mod would do so from the "access" tab of the room's overview page (accessed via the "info" link).

Comment: Human are bad at moderating themselves. Leave the job to [bots](https://stackapps.com/questions/7337/generic-bot-a-moderation-chatbot)

Answer (score 3):

If you message user [@Floern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559745/floern) on the [SEBotics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54445/sebotics) chatroom about the [@GenericBot](https://stackapps.com/questions/7337/generic-bot-a-moderation-chatbot) and ask about the [chatroom antifreeze feature](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49127871#49127871), your chatroom will live eternally.